# Scrollable Toplevel Window (tkinter)

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, toplevel

I'm pretty new to Python and have delopped a little program. In that program the user is able to open a Toplevel window as a popup which shows a map as an image file. I've managed to add a scrollbar to it and make the image scrollable.

The reason for the scrollbar is to support different screen resolutions so that if the shown image is too big, the user can scroll the content of the popup.

I now would like to ensure that the scrollbar changes size, when the popup window changes size or isn't completely stretched because of missing screen size. So far the scrollbar disappears as soon as you shrink the window size.

Here is my function that opens the popup window:

Comment: please add tkinter to your title and tag it

Comment: Could you look into providing a simple working code instead of just the function only? This will make helping you easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()` methods to get what you want given you are using the grid system to layout your widgets.

To help you further, I have commented out a section of your codes. Although your code displayed an image, it isn't the correct way to create an image in a Canvas. Your image was created in a Frame that sat on top of the Canvas. As such, you will not be able to scroll your image either although you can see the image and the scrollbar. Use the correct code I gave you instead.

Last comment. Do learn to provide a simplified complete code in the future so that you can attract help quicker. You can read more about about mcve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        header = "Toplevel"
        pfad = "NYCGifathon24-3.png" # change this to your image name
        source = "Canvas Image"
        self.karte(pfad,header,source)

    def karte(self, pfad,header,source): #added 'self' 
        popup = Toplevel()
        popup.title(header)

        ksbar=Scrollbar(popup, orient=VERTICAL)
        ksbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

        popCanv = Canvas(popup, width=600, height = 800,
                         scrollregion=(0,0,500,800)) #width=1256, height = 1674)
        popCanv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") #added sticky

        ksbar.config(command=popCanv.yview)
        popCanv.config(yscrollcommand = ksbar.set)

        ## Commented codes are inappropriate.
        ## Wrong way to create an image in Canvas.
        ## Your scrollbars will not be able to scroll the image either
        #kframe=Frame(popCanv, width=600, height = 800) 
        #kframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
        #img = PhotoImage(master=kframe, file=pfad)
        #imglabel = Label(kframe, image = img)
        #imglabel.image = img
        #imglabel.grid()
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=pfad) #amended
        image = popCanv.create_image(300, 400, image=self.img) #correct way of adding an image to canvas
        popCanv.create_text(420,790,text=source)

        popup.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) #added (answer to your question)
        popup.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) #added (answer to your question)

        #popup.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```