# Images do not get shown in a scroll view associated top-level window in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been trying to make a top-level window view which collects and shows all the images present in a folder in columns of 10. If the images were more than the allocated size of the window I wanted it to be possible to scroll through the images. I followed the answer given to [Scrollable Toplevel Window (tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513112/scrollable-toplevel-window-tkinter)
 to correctly add an image to a canvas and make it possible to scroll through them. But, in my case the entire popup window just comes out to be blank. Here is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def pop_up_window():
   win = Toplevel()

   vbar = tk.Scrollbar(win, orient = VERTICAL)
   vbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")

   container = tk.Canvas(win, height=300, width=720, scrollregion=(0, 0, 300, 720))
   container.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

   vbar.config(command=container.yview)
   container.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

   path = "D:\\image_collection"
   COLUMNS = 10
   image_count = 0

   for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')):
      image_count += 1
      r, c = divmod(image_count-1, COLUMNS)
      im = Image.open(infile)
      resized = im.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
      img_part = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(infile).resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS))
      image_in_canvas = container.create_image(r, c, image = img_part)

   win.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
   win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text='Call Pop-up window', command = pop_up_window)
button.place(x = 0, y = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to your images or it will be garbage collected by Python. A simple change can do it:

```
placeholder = []

def pop_up_window():
    ...

    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')):
       image_count += 1
       r, c = divmod(image_count-1, COLUMNS)
       im = Image.open(infile)
       img_part = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(infile).resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS))
       placeholder.append(img_part)
       image_in_canvas = container.create_image(r, c, image = img_part)
```

Also I want to point that the `create_image` method takes two coordinates as args. You are currently creating them as if they are grids, and it won't show up in the alignment you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but it have few issues with it. I fixed all of them or maybe most of them, in case I forgot to notice it.

- When creating an image in a function always create a reference to them as here you have many images so you can create a list to your `container`.
- To keep updating the `scrollregion` depending upon the amount of images bind "" to the `container` with the callback function  `lambda e: scrollregion=container.bbox('all')`.

***Here are the changes that I did to your `pop_up_window` function.***

```
...

path = "D:\\image_collection"
COLUMNS = 7
container.img_list = []
column = 0
row = 0

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')):
    if column >= COLUMNS: 
        column = 0
        row += 1
    im = Image.open(infile).resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    container.img_list.append(img)
    container.create_image(column*100+10, row*100+10, image = img, anchor='nw')
    column += 1

container.bind('<Configure>',lambda e:container.configure(scrollregion=container.bbox('all')))

...
```