# How do you stop a tkinter window being cut off by screen size whilst using grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm coding a window using the grid method since the data which I will be putting onto the window can vary, making it impractical to use place as this will lock the size of the window and cause formatting issues. A sample of the type of code I am using is as follows:

```
Location1_Label=tkinter.Label(frame1, text=Location1, font=("Calibri", 20))
Location1_Label.grid_configure(padx=(20,0), pady=(10,0))
Location1_Label.grid(column=3, row=2)
```

This should place the data within the grid in column 3 and row 2 with the data it is showing being a variable "Location1". This same way of formatting is used for the entire window with different pieces of data.

The issue is, is that with smaller monitor sizes, the width of the monitor is too small (pixel wise) to fit the end result of the entire window, so it ends up cutting off a portion of the window to fit the monitor. Is there a way to prevent this from happening and force it to create the entire window irrespective of the monitor size?

The properties which I've applied to the window are as follows if they're of any interest:

```
ViewPage=tkinter.Tk()
ViewPage.title("View Database")
ViewPage.resizable(False,False)
ViewPage.configure(bg="#0073CF")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well it depends on how you want to approach this, everything has it's downside and there is of course math included. But the simplest and for me most satisfying approach is to use a `Scrollbar`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Thingamabobs ah that could work, I'll have a look, thank you very much.

Comment: @Thingamabobs do you have an example of how you would implement this with a grid, I can't seem to find anything that works?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513112/scrollable-toplevel-window-tkinter).